# What is the difference between two 404 errors?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I get the same 404 error with the following 2 links:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/200

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/p/200

I'd like to catch the error, but with the first link I can't. With the second link I can, and its working properly.

What's the difference between two 404 errors?

Here is my code:

```
  deletePost(id: number)
  {
   return this.http.delete('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
   .pipe(
   catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    console.log("lalalalalalalala");
    return throwError(error);
    }
```

Comment: Because the first produces an HTTP 200?

Comment: Ok, the server accepted, and responded ok, but how can I catch the error if the Id is invalid?

Comment: You are catching errors. While it depends on the server processing the request, typically a 404 status code will not tell you something as specific as _unknown_ Id.

Comment: Thank you. I think, I understand. :)